# How would you call this

Tags: meaning

So alongside my house they are building a building so they had to do some excavation and left a deep (hole?).
Im not sure if hole is the correct term and right now they are people there so i wasn’t sure if saying “oh look there’s people in the hole” is correct

Answer (score 1):

As you indicated, I would call it an [*excavation*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/excavation):

> 2. a hole or hollow made by excavating.

So maybe:

> Look, there are some people in the **excavation**.

Informally, you could also call it a "hole in the ground".

Answer (score 0):

A hole is fine, though without context it could be man-made or otherwise.  So for clarity, I would simply add that it is a "hole for a building foundation".

Excavation would also be good as @user3169 mentions, though the first thing that comes to mind is a archeological dig, as in digging into the ground to uncover or reveal, which isn't quite the case here.  Still, it makes it clear that it is a man-made hole.